# Python-telegram-bot Get old messages in chat within two timestamps

Tags: linux, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How can I get **old** telegram messages?

*I'm saving interesting stuff found online via sharing these links to a Telegram bot.

I would like to make a "read it later"-like app, organizing these links into weeks.*

When I call the "bot.getUpdates" method, of course, I get -as expected- **new** messages.
What if I needed to get last week messages?
How can I get every message between two timestamps **in the past** using the python-telegram-bot API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such a feature in Telegram bot API. All you can do is to save the received messages to your own storage to use it later.

Comment: Thanks I understand. I have to log them in a file every time I call getUpdates and then trying to search them in the file. Maybe I will do a script to load them into a MySql database

Comment: Or you can add them to the database on the fly